# Global Inbox is missing alerts

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

There seems to be something up with the global inbox feature since the planned outage. I was alerted to a response of some sort (red blob) but upon visiting the inbox there's nothing there:

[image]

This is in Chrome 13 and Firefox 5 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 even after restarting both browsers.

**Updated:**

The comment added below red-blob alerted me and it's in the inbox but nothing else is there, i.e. the original alert described above.

Comment: same result on my end, IE 9.

Comment: For what it's worth, my inbox is normal, but I haven't gotten any new messages since the maintenance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a side effect of maintenance, it will work itself out eventually (next time your inbox is fully re-loaded).

I went ahead and bounced your inbox to speed the process up.